# Using https with localhost wamp

Tags: php, facebook, ssl, wamp

I am trying to run facebook App from my localhost .I made the canvas URL and secure Canvas URL to `http://localhost/myapp` and `https://localhost/myapp` .but the link `http://localhost/myapp` doesn't even work at my localhost.I enable mode_ssl and php_openssl extentions as well.I read different tutorials on internet but all invain. Anyone who already tested facebook apps on localhost.
Thanks

Comment: You need to lookup information about making a self-signed SSL, and the proper apache configuration for it. I think you'll need to make a virtual host instead of using localhost too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't bothered making a self signed certificate to test facebook apps, what I have done though is make sure secure browsing is turned off on facebook. Then you should be able to hit the `http://localhost/myapp` and it won't redirect you.

Comment: Feb 2014 facebooks disables the secure browsing setting. Its default on now.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it properly, try following this tutorial:

http://www.phpjoel.com/2011/04/07/installing-ssl-using-openssl-on-a-wamp-localhost/

The issue isn't anything to do with Facebook, so just concentrate on getting it without facebook first.